# Mutating a boolean column in dplyr for 1 and 0, using ifelse() gives values above 1

Tags: r, boolean, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a column with tips in my dataframe and will try to run a logistic regression to predict if a tip will be left or now.

Trying to create a boolean column in my data, having 1 and 0, using `mutate`. `1` for a tip, `0` for no tip.

My code is pretty simple:

```
data %>% mutate(ifelse((Tips > 0, 1), ifelse(Tips == 0, 0)))
```

As an output I have values, which go above 1, for instance, tip = 7.00 converts to boolean value 7, which is not what I expect.

```
Tips boolean
1.75    1
2.00    2
0.00    0
2.35    2
0.00    0
1.00    1
0.00    0
0.00    0
7.00    7
0.00    0
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work but I guess you were trying to do something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(boolean = ifelse(Tips > 0, 1, ifelse(Tips == 0, 0, NA)))
```

Or if you have many conditions to check use `case_when` which is cleaner.

```
data %>% mutate(boolean = case_when(Tips > 0 ~ 1, 
                                    Tips == 0 ~ 0))
```

---

Assuming `Tips` would always have 0 or a positive value you don't need any `ifelse` at all.

```
data$boolean <- +(data$Tips > 0)
```

Or use `sign` which returns 0 for 0 values and 1 for any number greater than 0.

```
data$boolean <- sign(data$Tips)
```